# Remove IntelliJ from ubuntu 15

Tags: intellij-idea

How to find out the installation directory of IntelliJ IDE in ubuntu 15 ? Actually I want to delete that particular IDE. How should I go to  ***'opt/directory'*** using terminal or directly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no fixed installation directory for IntelliJ IDEA under Ubuntu. The Linux distribution of IntelliJ IDEA is a .tar.gz archive which can be unpacked into any directory.

If you do not know where it was installed, you can try to locate the installation by running a command like `find . -name idea.jar` from the root directory of your system.

Comment: To find an arbitrary file on you linux box you can use `locate FILENAME`. The index to that database can be update with `sudo updatedb`

Answer (score 0):

Delete IntellijIdea*.tar.gz and `.IntellijIdea*`dir in your homedir.

then do:

`rm -rf ~/.IntellijIdea2017.1`